# How to remove filter from table in excel created by spreadsheet-light import data from a DataTable function.

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetlight

I'm using Spreadsheet-light for creating excel document. I need to use a method "import data from a DataTable".But the table has filter by default. i do not want this filter.

[image]

I tried a inbuilt method of Spreadsheet-light

```
sl.RemoveFilter();
```

to remove the filter but it's not working.Can any one suggest how to remove this default filter. 
Please look into my code.

```
int iStartRowIndex = 11;
int iStartColumnIndex = 2;
sl.ImportDataTable(iStartRowIndex, iStartColumnIndex, dtMyTable,true);
int iEndRowIndex = iStartRowIndex + dtMyTable.Rows.Count + 1 - 1;
int iEndColumnIndex = iStartColumnIndex + dtMyTable.Columns.Count - 1;
SLTable table = sl.CreateTable(iStartRowIndex, iStartColumnIndex, iEndRowIndex, iEndColumnIndex);
table.SetTableStyle(SLTableStyleTypeValues.Medium17);
sl.RemoveFilter();
sl.InsertTable(table);
sl.SaveAs("FileName");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might come as a shock to you, but the solution is weirdly simple..

Just replace the statement

```
sl.RemoveFilter();
```

with this:

```
table.HasAutoFilter = false;
```

It took me some time to figure this out.. Some documentation is definitely needed for this!!